# Objective C Iphone take photos both cameras simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I need to take one picture from rear camera and another from back camera. I read that it wouldn´t possible at same time, but, you know if it is possible to switch between cameras in thi minimum time and try to take one fron and one back picture?

EDIT:

As I said before, I want to capture from both cameras at the same time. I know that it is not possible on Iphone devices but i tried to switch cameras very quickly. Iphone waste a lot of time switching between cameras. The ideal is to show in preview back camera and record frames from it, and record frames in front camera at the same time without previewing it and do not lose the front preview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use avfoundation to take pictures.

Comment: Thanks, I know it, but is ti possible to take picas from both cameras at same time?

Comment: No. Use Avfoundation to toggle between front and back to take pictures.

Comment: Anyone knows any wat to do automattically i.e., take a pic, switch camera, take another pic and switch to go to the next capture cycle without user intervention?